# Cannot publish dynamic web project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I unzipped a fresh copy of Tomcat 9 in my user directory and configured the server under eclipse. I created a dynamic web project and an index.html file in my web content directory. When I run the project I cannot access my it at http://localhost:8080/project/index.html.

Comment: Deployment requires that you allow the workspace to build. Are you letting it build before it runs?

Comment: I have automatic build enabled.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I deploy using the run configuration"?

Comment: Pressing the run button runs one of the run configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eclipse project name consisted of two words. Once I renamed the project to a single word, I was able to deploy and access the website.